# How was Vc(t) found in this source free RC circuit?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistance, remote-control

Shuldn't \$v_c(t)\$ be the same as \$10^4\space i_s\$ after \$t=0\$?[image]

Comment: Current dependent voltage source

Comment: Anyway, something doesn't make sense here. \$V_c(t)\$ should depend on \$t\$. Unless you have been given some specific \$t\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When \$t < 0\$ (Which is *not* the same as "after \$t=0\$"), then yes, \$10^4\space i_s = v_c(t)\$. That's exactly what the final line of working out says. (Hint: what is \$2/3 \mathrm{mA} \times 10^4\$?).

The implication of \$t=0\$ above the switch is that the switch is closed from \$t=-\infty\$ to \$t=0\$, so it is in a steady state condition just before the switch is opened. In steady state the capacitor is fully charged and all the supply current is flowing through the current dependent voltage source.

Comment: Isn't it a current dependent voltage source?

Comment: @Maya ah, you're right there - not a current source.